# How to block competitor's Google AdSense ads from being displayed on my website?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-ads

We are looking into adding Google Adsense for our website but are a bit concerned about our competitors' ads getting displayed on our website. We know how to block individual domains from "Block advertiser URLs" section but the problem is, one of our competitors directly link their Youtube channel videos to their ads - when you click on the ad it takes you to that particular channel's video. If we block Youtube's domain, then we wont be able to display ads of our own Youtube channel. How can we block our competitor's Youtube links? Is there an option in "Block advertiser URLs" section to block URLs that contain our competitor's Youtube channel's ID?

Comment: Why would you want to display ads for your own YouTube channel on your website? You could directly link to your YouTube channel without paying for the cost of ads.

Comment: Yes I could do that, but having a centralized ad platform makes things more manageable.

Comment: Our ads would also display on other websites and other websites' ads would also display on ours. (as to why would we want our own ads displayed on our own website). It's a bit counter intuitive I agree. But that is exactly what our competitor does for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose to block each competitor's video or their entire channel.

From the Google docs:

> - Block a single video by entering its URL: youtube.com/watch?v=videoID
> - Block all YouTube videos: youtube.com/watch
> - Block an entire YouTube channel by watch domain: youtube.com/channel/channelID

You can do that on the Adsense console by going to:
**Blocking Controls >>> YouTube Host >>> Manage Advertiser URL**